# Android, отступ "dropDown" меню у спиннера

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

Имею горизонтальный `LinearLayout`, содержащий `TextView` и `Spinner`, которые занимают одинаковое количество места:

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/control_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:paddingBottom="4dp"
     android:paddingEnd="8dp"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     android:paddingStart="8dp"
     android:paddingTop="4dp"
     android:weightSum="2">

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/filter"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="end"
             android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
             android:minEms="12"
             android:minHeight="@dimen/touch_target_size"
             android:padding="16dp"
             android:text="@string/filters"
          android:textColor="@drawable/button_filter_text_color_selector"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
             android:id="@+id/sortOrder"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="48dp"
             android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:paddingRight="16dp"
             android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

На экране это выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cпиннер справа. Вот что происходит при нажатии на него:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меню есть отступ слева, но нет отступа справа. На самом деле слева не совсем отступ а просто урезание ширины, которое я делаю из кода:

```
sortOrder.setDropDownWidth(size.x - (int) SizeUtils.dpToPx(this, 8));
```

8dp - это отступ `LinearLayout`. Справа ничего таким макаром "обрезать" не получится.

Меню перекрывает `TextView`, так и задумано. Я не могу исхитриться и добавить отступ справа. Как мне быть, учитывая что мне нужен имено `DropDownMenu`?

**UPD:** можно поменять элементы местами и всё заработает, но это не вариант.

**UPD1:** Jarvis_J дал совет что нужно работать с вьюшкой из адаптера. Я убился, но к успеху не пришёл. Вью никак не реагирует ни на `margin`, ни на `width` и `height`.

**Вьюха:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_divider"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/menuBgColor"
    tools:text="item1" />
```

Метод внутри адаптера(`extends ArrayAdapter<Option>`):

```
 @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final SortOption sortOption = sortOptions.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_order_dropdown_item, null);
        }

        TextView label = convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        label.setText(sortOption.getLabel().toUpperCase());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Я предпринял ряд попыток добавить `margin` через код, но ни к чему не пришёл(публикую последние варианты, их было много):

```
 //Не работает
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
 label.setLayoutParams(params);

  //Не работает
  LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
  label.setLayoutParams(params);
```

- метод `label.getLayoutParams()` возвращает null, т.к элемент не отрисован.

**UPD2:** Не останавливаемся и едем дальше. Расширяю вопрос.

Код адаптера:

```
public class SortOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SortOption> {

    public static final int SORT_NOT_SELECTED = -1;

    private List<SortOption> sortOptions = Collections.emptyList();

    public SortOptionAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.spinner_order_item);
    }

    public void setItems(List<SortOption> sortOptions) {
        if (PojoUtils.isNotNull(sortOptions)) {
            this.sortOptions = sortOptions;
            clear();
            addAll(sortOptions);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        for (SortOption option : sortOptions) {
            if (option.isSelected()) {
                return sortOptions.indexOf(option);
            }
        }
        return SORT_NOT_SELECTED;
    }

    public SortOption getItem(int position) {
        return sortOptions.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final SortOption sortOption = sortOptions.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_order_item, null);
            convertView.setEnabled(parent.isEnabled());
        }

        final TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        label.setText(sortOption.getLabel().toUpperCase());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final SortOption sortOption = sortOptions.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.spinner_order_dropdown_item, null);
        }

        TextView label = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        label.setText(sortOption.getLabel().toUpperCase());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Как видите, в адаптере используется два `View` - в моём понимаии один для первого элемента, второй для всех последующих. Вторая вью уже была опубликована здесь, поэтому публикую первую:

**spinner_order_dropdown_item**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_divider"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/menuBgColor"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    tools:text="по популярности" />
```

Было обнаружена следующая вещь:

1) В адаптере можно написать следующее:

```
@Override
public void setDropDownViewTheme(@Nullable Resources.Theme theme) {
    theme.applyStyle(R.style.CatalogItemSpinner,true);
    super.setDropDownViewTheme(theme);
    }
```

А в стиле:

```
<style name="CatalogItemSpinner">
     <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Это приведёт к тому что всё на экране получит `paddingEnd` на 8dp. Это исказит картину в целом, но достигнутый эффект станет гораздо ближе. Для меня это значит что границу всё же можно как - то сместить padding - ом. Правда при таком решении внутри самого меню справа тоже появятся отступы(на скрине возможно не видно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Был получен совет попробовать `Popup Listview`, результатов пока нет(кроме неудачных).

**UPD3**:

Существует более - менее сносное решение:

В самом спиннере:

```
android:popupTheme="@style/CatalogItemSpinner"
```

В стилях:

```
 <style name="CatalogItemSpinner">
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_item_divider</item>
    </style>
```

Единственное, что никак не получается побороть: при таком решении отступ делается как снаружи меню, так и внутри него. Поэтому пока что это не вариант, хотя уже практически то что нужно.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите. Почему не получится обрезать справа?

Comment: Хочу чтобы при нажатии на спиннер у его меню был отступ справа, такой же как и слева. Сейчас слева отступ есть а справа нету(второй скрин). Обрезать не получится, потому что через код я меняю ширину самого элемента, и он обрезается только слева, справа нет. И ни один xml аргумент, который я применяю к Spinner, мне не помогает, а перепробовал я их дофига - margin, padding, оффсеты, вообще всё перепробовал наверное.

Comment: Отступ нужен в спиннере или выпадающем меню?

Comment: В меню. Отступ самого элемента от края экрана.

Comment: Если в меню - нужно работать не со спиннером, а с вью из адаптера

Comment: Спасибо что направили в нужную сторону. Только я всё ещё не справился. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90152/discussion-between-jarvis-j-and-kirstenly).